# Check iOS device current state

Tags: ios, iphone, reporting

I want to write an app that helps the user keep track of how often they use their iPhone. Is there any way for an iOS app to periodically report to a server the amount of time during the day that the device has been active? Preferably a solution that doesn’t involve keeping the app open in the background. Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: Not with any public APIs, no.

Answer (score 1):

For security purposes, an `iOS` app’s interactions with the file system **are limited** to the directories inside the app’s sandbox directory.

You can learn more on [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).